# How to solve "Cannot connect to solving process (communication interfaces)" error in CPLEX (Windows)?

Tags: cplex

When I try to run CPLEX model, I encounter "Cannot connect to solving process (communication interfaces)". Could you please help how to solve it?

I tried to run CPLEX to solve a model and I expect an optimal solution since model is small.

Comment: Can you try to run with command line oplrun ?
And share your model so that other users could try ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm able to solve via oplrun. However, I wonder if it's possible to solve this error in OPL?

Comment: I found the problem. My username includes different characters. When I changed directory the problem is solved.